# Ionic - How to add platforms and plugins folder on Github Repository

Tags: git, github, ionic-framework

I'm using git-bash to add Ionic project on Github repository. It adds all files except for platforms and plugins folders, but I want to push them also. Read that they are ignored by default and I can't find a way to push them :(.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a file called .gitignore (Which might be hidden) in the root folder. Just open the file using text editor and remove the entries for those folders.

Comment: Oh I think that solved the problem. It was no-named text file didn't see it. Thanks.